# Definite integral $\int _{-1}^1\:\frac{\arccos\left(x\right)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Do you have any idea about how should I approach this integral? I tried various substitutions and ended up nowhere.
$$\int _{-1}^1\:\frac{\arccos\left(x\right)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: Wolfram alpha does give a general solution to the Integral, while using non-elementary functions (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arccos(x)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)+dx). @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How did you come up with this? Did you use a symbolic integrator?

Comment: for many years ago i have solved this, written in an old notebook

Comment: i haven't a symbolic Integrator in use, Maple can't solve this integral

Comment: This looks like a job for contour integration

Comment: from where do you got this Version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitute $x\mapsto-x$, then average the two integrals:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\arccos(x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\pi-\arccos(x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi2\int_{-1}^1\frac1{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: using integration by part you will get  :

$$\int _{-1}^1\:\frac{\arccos\left(x\right)}{1+x^2}dx= [_{-1}^{1} \arccos x\arctan x +\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{\sqrt[] {1-x²} }=\frac{\pi²}{4}$$ because you have [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(arctanx%2F(sqrt(1-x%C2%B2))+,+x%3D-1+to+1):$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan x}{\sqrt{1-x²}}=0$ as $\arctan$ is odd function over symetric domain.

Comment: (+1) You don't even need to refer to wolfram. The integrand of the last integral is odd on a symmetric interval around zero, so... Zero! However you need to show that it converges which is a little bit trivial this case.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make the substitution $$x=\cos t\implies dx=-\sin t\cdot dt$$
And your integral becomes:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\arccos(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{\arccos(\cos t)}{1+(\cos t)^2}(-\sin t)dt=\\=-\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{t\cdot\sin t}{1+(\cos t)^2}dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{t\cdot\sin t}{1+(\cos t)^2}dt=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}$$

---

Now I will show you how to compute the last step.

In order to compute 
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{t\cdot\sin t}{1+(\cos t)^2}dt$$
we have first to make the substitution $y=\pi -x\implies dx=-dy$
Then $$I=\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{(\pi-y)\sin (\pi-y)}{1+(\cos (\pi -y))^2}(-dy)=\\=\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{(\pi-y)[\sin(\pi)\cos(y)-\cos(\pi)\sin(y)]}{1+[\cos(\pi)
\cos(y)-\sin(\pi)\sin(y)]^2}(-dy)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-y)\cdot\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}dy$$
Now split it into two integrals and we see that
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\pi-y)\cdot\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}dy=\\=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}dy-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{y\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}dy$$
That is $$I=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}dy-I$$ or, in other words, $$I=\frac{\pi}2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin y}{1+(\cos y)^2}dy$$
Now we havo to make a second substitution: $u=\cos y\implies dy=-\frac{du}{\sin y}$

$$I=\frac{\pi}2\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{\sin y}{1+u^2}\left(-\frac{du}{\sin y}\right)=-\frac{\pi}2\int_{1}^{-1}\frac {du}{1+u^2}=\frac{\pi}2\left[\arctan(u)\right]_{-1}^{1}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}$$

Comment: I used the exact same substitution but I didn't know how to solve the last integral.

Comment: a nice solution!

Comment: Very nice! And the book is quite amazing, I need to browse it again sometime