# I have the integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arccos(x)}{1+x^2} \,dx $ and some questions. Any help appreciated!

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arccos(x)}{1+x^2} \,dx $$

Hi everyone! Sorry for my poor formatting skills, I'm still quite new to this platform.

I do not know how to solve this integral.

Things that I tried but failed miserably:

- I've tried substituting $t = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ but this (of course) does not work since its $\arccos(x)$ and not $\arctan(x)$.
- I've tried solving it by parts but that also leads to a dead-end.
- Since the bounds are $1$ and $-1$, I tried checking if the function is even or odd but $\arccos(x)$ is neither.

My questions (even though they might sound ridiculous or noobish) are:

- Is there a Weierstrass-like substitution for inverse trigonometric functions? (tried googling it but to no avail)
- How would one go about solving this type of integral?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Indefinite integral cannot be expressed in elementary functions but can be expressed using dilogarithms. You can decompose this fraction using that $1+x^2=(x+i)(x-i)$ then apply Euler's formula's.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635503/definite-integral-int-11-frac-arccos-leftx-right1x2dx?noredirect=1

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you very much !

Comment: @Svyatoslav good, how did you find the duplicate?

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Carccos(x)%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D%20%5C%2Cdx%24&p=1  Using this link and typing the formula in you can find different solutions on different sites

Comment: @Svyatoslav thanks, have a great week! :-)

Comment: @4444 the same to you :)

Answer (score 3):

I offer another approach.

You can consider the integral $I(a) = \displaystyle{\int}_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{\arccos ax}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x$. Then
$$
I'(a) = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\arccos ax}{1+x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x=-\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-a^2 x^2}}\frac{1}{1+x^2} \ \mathrm{d}x=0
$$
The last step is because the integrand is odd. Finally, the integral can be calculated as
$$
I(1) = \int_{0}^{1} I'(a) \ \mathrm{d}a +I(0) = I(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I put this problem for a high school integration bee.
Here's my fastest solution!!

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)+(\sin^{-1}(x)-\sin^{-1}(x))}{x^2+1}dx$$

Note that $\cos^{-1}(x)+\sin^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and arcsinx is an odd function, so by symmetry the leftover arcsinx term is 0.

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x^2+1}dx=\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}$$

Comment: +1 for the creative solution :)

Answer (score 0):

By using king property :

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arccos(x)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arccos(-x)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x $$.

So :

$$2I = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arccos(x)+\arccos(-x)}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\pi}{1+x^2} $$.

Consequently :

$$I = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \left[ \arctan(x) \right]_{-1}^{1} = \frac{\pi^2}{4} = \frac{3\zeta(2)}{2} $$.

Comment: $\frac{2\zeta(2)}{3}=\frac{2\pi^2}{3\cdot 6}=\frac{\pi^2}9$

Comment: You meant $\frac32\zeta(2)$, but why are you bringing up $\zeta(2)$ anyway?

Comment: For the STYLE eh